# Java simple backup and restore Class

Tags: java, backup, restore

I'm working on a school project with a simple backup and restore class in `Java`.  It has two methods, one for backup, and one for restore, that break the file down into sized chunks determined by the program, and using the restore rebuilds the file from those chunks.

*Specifically, I am stuck on the backup part:*

I want to split the file into smaller pieces equal in size to partSize, and create output files named `filename.1, filename.2, etc`. and then return an integer with the count files created.

**Here is my code:**

```
    public static int backup(String filename, double partSize) throws Exception {
    BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
    int splitFileSize = (int) (partSize * 1024 * 1024);
    int numberOfPieces = (input.available() / splitFileSize) + 1;
    String fn = "filename.";
    int i = 1;
    int b = 0;
    BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fn + i));
    while (numberOfPieces > 0) {
        output.write(input.read());
        b++;
        if (b == splitFileSize) {
            output.close();
            i++;
            numberOfPieces--;
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fn + i));
        }
    }
    output.close();
    input.close();
    System.out.println("Number of files created: ");
    return i;
}
```

**Note:** In testing, I think its stuck in an infinite loop. Any idea why?

Thank you! And thank you for the edit to make things clearer!

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: No, to be perfectly honest debugging in eclipse is difficult for me to grasp.

Comment: It's one of the most crucial skills you'll acquire as a new programmer. Might as well get started now.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for opening my eyes to that. I actually completely forgot about it, I have to brush up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't reset the b value when your if run.
You create a new file, but the b variable continues to increase, so your if will execute only once.
try add a line inside your if that set b value to 0.

```
    if (b == splitFileSize) {
        output.close();
        i++;
        numberOfPieces--;
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fn + i));
        b=0;
    }
```

Comment: That stopped the infinite loop! Thanks! But now it doesn't return a value.

Comment: what is exactly happening? return something different? or don't return nothing (i.e. throwing an exception or an error)?

Comment: It's just:    Number of files created:      And then nothing.

Comment: This is just a print. not the return. your println doesn't have a variable to print.

Comment: Ugh. Stupid overlook. Thank you so much. I'm seriously embarrassed by that.